# Subtraction of iterators and integers

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator

I'm researching the basic sorting algorithms and I was looking about Shell Sort here:
https://github.com/nicolausYes/iterator-template-sort-library/blob/master/src/ShellSort.h

Here is the relevant code:

```
template< class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare >
static void sort( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp )
{
    auto size = last - first;
    auto h = 1;
    while( h < size / 3 ) h = 3 * h + 1;

    while( h >= 1 )
    {
        for( auto i = first + h; i != last; i++ )
        {
            for( auto j = i; (j - first) >= h && comp(*j, *(j-h)); j -= h )
                std::swap( *j, *(j-h) );
        }

        h /= 3;
    }
}
```

When he declares size, is it supposed to be an integral value or another iterator? Because he's dividing it by numbers later like this : "size / 3"
But when he calls std::swap(*j, *(j - h)); he's swapping the insides of 2 iterators, so there j - h returns an iterator. If "size" is an iterator then, what does / do to it? I mean if it just splits the internal pointer by 3, that would make no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtracting **one iterator from another** should yield an integer. The STL's random access iterators yield a value of type `ptrdiff_t` when subtracted. It's good practice to use this type when implementing iterators in general. However, in practice, if you want to use, say, `int`, that's usually fine too.

Subtracting **an integer from an iterator** yields another iterator.

Comment: More precisely worded: the results of subtraction of iterators must be a signed integral type.  _If_ you're using the standard allocators, it will always be `ptrdiff_t`.  You can, however, define your own allocators, instantiate containers with them, and change this.  (If what you change it too isn't a signed integral type, then you have undefined behavior.)

Comment: but what about the line where he uses std::swap( *j, *(j-h) ); ?
Here he is dereferencing the result of iterator subtraction.

Comment: @shortage_radeon `h` has type `int`